# ZeroMQ and simple messaging with just-in-time connection and disconnection

Tags: zeromq

With using HTTP, I can develop server-to-server communication code easily. For example,

At Server1,

```
func1()
{
    curl("https://server2/func2");
}

[route("func3")]
func3()
{
    // finished!
}
```

At Server2,

```
[route("func2")]
func2()
{
    curl("https://server1/func3");
}
```

Using these two (curl and http response code), I don't need to write to socket connection or disconnection or socket accept. Yes, it is convenient.

However, HTTP is heavy for me. Performance matters. I don't need HTTP nor SSL. HTTP requests involves one time TCP connection and disconnect for each request.

I am looking for a simple networking module like this:

1. Internally, If the server-to-server communication does not exists, establish one just-in-time, then send a message. If it exists, reuse it.
2. Internally, If the server-to-server communication is unused for a long time, disconnect it.
3. A server simply sends a message to other server, regardless of the connection exists or not.
4. There is no relay or broker process between servers. Servers communicate directly.

I found ZeroMQ. ZeroMQ provides many [networking patterns](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc86) with fancy name, for example, Titanic or Espresso. I looked for which fulfills what are described above in ZeroMQ, but I cannot find it. Lazy Pirate seems to be a similar one, but it involves [connection and disconnection statements](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:lpclient).

With ZeroMQ, can I do it?